# Strange behaviour with Android Activity Lifecycle when connecting to Google API Client

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, google-api-client, activity-lifecycle

In the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), it says of **onRestart** (emphasis mine):

> Called after onStop() when the current activity is being re-displayed to the user (the user has navigated back to it). *It will be followed by onStart() and then onResume()*.

Now in my app, as recommended, I (attempt to) connect to the 'Google API Client' in **onStart** and disconnect in **onStop** like so: (simplified)...

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleAPIClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleAPIClient.disconnect();
}
```

I accidentally launched my app and immediately pressed home key get get rid of it, it went into the background, and then a few seconds later, popped back into life and started to attempt to connect the googleAPIClient.  This only happened if the home key (or the overview key for that matter) was pressed quickly - ie, before the connecting dialogue had a chance to appear (or put another way, before mGoogleApiClient.connect() was even called).

Upon further testing, it became obvious that if I removed mGoogleAPIClient.connect() from **onStart**, it stayed in the background as was expected/required.  I also confirmed that when it happens, **onRestart** is being called, and indeed, it *is* being called before **onStart** is invoked.  However, this doesn't make any sense to me.

If the problem is being caused by mGoogleAPIClient trying to connect (and when doing so, bringing the activity back to the foreground), and mGoogleAPIClient.connect() is being called in **onStart** which is called *after* **onRestart**, how can **onRestart** know to be called if the event has not happened at that point?

I'd also confirm that I've tried at least 2 other apps from the Play Store that also exhibit this behaviour.

It's a problem that could easily pop up as it's all too easy to launch something by mistake and then send it to the background straight away, so I have implemented a workaround using boolean flags and now the problem only happens if you launch, press home/overview and immediately re-launch and background the app again (all before the dialogue comes up).  I don't expect anyone to do this, but I'm left wondering, is this a bug of am I doing something wrong here or misunderstanding something and how do I stop this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: super.onStop() ?

Comment: `before the connecting dialogue had a chance to appear` what is the connecting dialog?

Comment: @iGio90, typo - corrected :-)

Comment: @natario, Sorry, when you connect to the Google API client, you get a dialog that appears on the screen (in my case, I'm connecting to Play Games Services) - this is the dialog to which I'm referring. It comes up with a Play Games logo, then an account picker screen.

Comment: I think you are looking at it wrong, IMO it is the **first** call to `onStart` that fires the dialog. When the dialog is ready, `onRestart` and `onStart` are called again, but connect() is useless at that point.

Comment: @natario, yes of course you're right, I don't know why I didn't see that. For some reason, I was assuming that if the home key was pressed *during* onStart, then onPause/onStop would immediately jump in.  Thanks for clearing that up.  Would you have any suggestions as to how this could be avoided (I mean, if a user backgrounds an app, the last thing they want is it springing into life again on it's own 3 seconds later), cheers.

Comment: I think there’s nothing you can do, other than filing a bug report / feature request

Comment: @natario, no problem.  I have a workaround in place so that should suffice for now.  If you want to post your explanation as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play Games dialog you are talking about requires some time to be laid out (guess play services has to connect to their APIs), so chances are that:

- you open the app and `onStart()` is called
- client starts connecting
- you close the app
- client background work succeeds, and app is brought to the foreground
- `onRestart()` and `onStart()` are called in this order, just like the docs say. At this point the `connect()` call is useless.

Since this is internal behavior, there’s not much we can do in my opinion, other than disconnecting the client `onStop()`. If you feel this is important, you might try to file a bug / feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the connect() happens in background, your quick pressing of key bypasses disconnect()(the state doesn't get set by connect()) so for the same connection, it assumes it is safe to show the dialog even it has to bring up the App again.

You can try the following:

```
// Check if it is not already connected in onStart()
if(!mGoogleAPIClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleAPIClient.isConnecting()){
    mGoogleAPIClient.connect();
}
```

Secondly, make the call to `disconnect()` blocking in `onStop()`:

```
while(true){
    if(mGoogleAPIClient.isConnected()){
    mGoogleAPIClient.disconnect();
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pulp_fiction, unfortunately, this didn't work - also the while loop won't compile, I get an "Operator '!' cannot be applied to 'void' - I assume because the disconnect method doesn't return a boolean (it actually doesn't return anything) :-(  Thanks

Comment: @Zippy : My bad for being unmindful on that. See now.

Comment: @Zippy : One more thing, are you using AutoManage of the API?